# Convert multipart/form-data cURL to Fetch node js

Tags: node.js, curl, fetch, apache-pulsar

With the following cURL request I am able to successfully interact with a pulsar api to update the configurations of a function.

#### Working cURL Request

> curl  --request PUT  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F functionConfig='{"parallelism":2};type=application/json' http://pulsar-test:8080/admin/v3/functions/test/ingest/test-entity-FeedTransformer

But I'm having trouble converting to an equivalent fetch request in Node.

Note: I'm using [formdata-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-node) to import FormData.

```
import { FormData } from 'formdata-node'
```

#### Non Working Fetch (Bad Request)

```
    const body = new FormData()
    body.append('functionConfig', '{"parallelism":2};type=application/json')

    return fetch(
      'http://pulsar-test:8080/admin/v3/functions/test/ingest/test-entity-FeedTransformer',
      {
        body,
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer abcd'
        },
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    )
```

Apparently the form data is not being set in a way the api server can recognize.
`{"reason":"Function config is not provided"}`

What am I missing here?

Comment: try removing `headers` property from fetch options

Comment: @traynor thanks for the suggestion, I tried but I'm still getting "Bad Request"

Comment: @traynor, removing the Content Type property from the header was a step forward as I am now getting some text back from the server. `{"reason":"Function config is not provided"}`

The server just isn't recognizing the form data.

Comment: Which package do you use for `fetch`? For example, unlike the browser API, `node-fetch` does not automatically add the `Content-Type` header when you send a `FormData` as payload.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is most likely that multipart request is not recognized/not well formed, or something like that, so try using another library, here's an example with [Form-Data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data):

```
import { FormData } from 'form-data';

const body = new FormData();

body.append('functionConfig', '{"parallelism":2};type=application/json')

return fetch(
    'http://pulsar-test:8080/admin/v3/functions/test/ingest/test-entity-FeedTransformer', {
        body,
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer abcd'
        },
        method: 'PUT'
    }
)
```

alternatively, you could run your `curl` command with [child-process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback)

see: [How to use curl with exec nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189849/how-to-use-curl-with-exec-nodejs)